I need to start my 95 Jeep YJ and I've lost the key. Is it possible to crank it without the key?
Okay so I have a 1995 Jeep wrangler yj. I have lost the key that will crank the jeep, but I have the door key.(Unsure why there is different keys for the ignition and doors) This hasn't been an issue until recently when my daily driver broke down on me and now I am desperately in need to use my jeep to get to work. I've already missed 3 days and I have a perfectly good jeep I can drive sitting in my driveway but I've lost the key! Can somebody point me in the right direction for how I can crank my jeep without the key? I don't have money to pay a locksmith at this time. Please help!!!

I don't know how we can help you without knowing if your Jeep has an immobilizer or a chip key and/or a steering wheel lock. I don't mean to pile on, but deciding on day 1 not to pay a locksmith has caused you to lose two additional days' pay. This decision gets worse and worse with every day of work you miss. Please reconsider.
